# Global counter not updating in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
import time

counter = 0

def create():
    global counter
    print "The value of counter currently"
    print counter
    counter =+ 1
    print counter
    print "The value of counter after increment"

while True:

    create()
    time.sleep(3)
```

All I am trying to do in the above code is increment the global value increasingly to infinity. But I end with an output like below. What am I doing wrong in this python code?

```
The value of counter currently
0
1
The value of counter after increment

The value of counter currently
1
1
The value of counter after increment

The value of counter currently
1 
1
The value of counter after increment
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple typo.

```
counter =+ 1
```

(which is equivalent to `counter = +1`; reassigning `1` to the `counter`)

should be replaced with

```
counter += 1
```

Comment: This blocked my hundred lines of code. Damn!.. Other than laughing at myself, Now I also understand why python even didnt throw up an error.. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @SuhasChikkanna, You're welcome. Happy python programming.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, you need to change `counter =+ 1` to `counter += 1`.

```
import time

counter = 0

def create():
    global counter
    print "The value of counter currently"
    print counter
    counter += 1
    print counter
    print "The value of counter after increment"

while True:

    create()
    time.sleep(3)
```